# Accessing the array from PHP Client library for Exact Online

Tags: php, exact-online, picqer-exact-php-client

In order to store orders placed by customers with certain information from the WooCommerce REST API to the Exact Online dashboard via [REST API](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=BulkCRMAccounts). I had used [PHP Client library for Exact Online](https://github.com/picqer/exact-php-client).

While there was an issue -- after storing the data to Exact Online couldn't able to access the particular fields from an array. Specifically, when an REST API call has been made with

```
 /api/v1/{division}/bulk/CRM/Accounts?
 $filter=ID eq Email eq'nishanth@gmail.com'&$select=ID,Email
```

OR

```
$url = "https://start.exactonline.de/api/v1/" + mandant.number + "/crm/Accounts?
$filter=Email eq '" + orderitem.email + "'&$select=ID,Code";
```

Here you will the below code

```
$customer = [
        'address'       => 'No.22/N, 91 Cross, XYZ Street, ABC Road',
        'address2'      => 'DEF',
        'city'          => 'GHI',
        'customerid'    => '999',
        'country'       => 'DE',
        'name'          => 'Nishanth',
        'zipcode'       => '123456'
];


// Create a new account

$account->AddressLine1 = $customer['address'];
$account->AddressLine2 = $customer['address2'];
$account->City = $customer['city'];
$account->Code = $customer['customerid'];
$account->Country = $customer['country'];
$account->IsSales = 'true';
$account->Name = $customer['name'];
$account->Postcode = $customer['zipcode'];
$account->Email = 'nishanth@gmail.com';
$account->Status = 'C';
$account->save();
```

This was the result obtained after filtering with Email ID

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($account->filter("Email eq 'nishanth@gmail.com'"));


[attributes:protected] => Array
 (
    [Accountant] => 
    [AddressLine1] => No.22/N, 91 Cross, XYZ Street, ABC Road
    [AddressLine2] => DEF
    [City] => GHI
    [Code] => 1000
    [ConsolidationScenario] => 6
    [Country] => DE 
    [CountryName] => Germany
    [Created] => /Date(1555764341137)/
    [Creator] => 5bbfbd93-52f1-4f4b-b34e-fd213e479f8e
    [CreatorFullName] => Nishanth
    [Division] => 54810
    [Email] => nishanth@gmail.com
    [ID] => bb124287-647c-4267-bd60-004efa1302aa
    [LogoThumbnailUrl] => https://start.exactonline.de//docs/images/placeholder_account_myeol.png
    [LogoUrl] => https://start.exactonline.de//docs/images/placeholder_account_myeol.png
    [Modified] => /Date(1555764341137)/
    [Modifier] => 5bbfbd93-52f1-4f4b-b34e-fd213e479f8e
    [ModifierFullName] => Nishanth
    [Name] => Nishanth Jay
    [Postcode] => 123456
 )
```

Making use of below built-In functions such as,

```php
public function find()
{
    $result = $this->connection()->get($this->url);
    return new self($this->connection(), $result);
}
```

```php
public function findWithSelect($select = '')
{
    $result = $this->connection()->get($this->url, [
        '$select' => $select
    ]);

    return new self($this->connection(), $result);
}
```

Despite calling with the built-In functions below:

```php
$Accounts->filter("Email eq 'nishanth@gmail.com'")[0]->findWithSelect('ID');

$checkAccount = $Accounts->filter("Email eq 'nishanth@gmail.com'");
$checkAccount[0]->find('ID');
$checkAccount[0]->findWithSelect('Code');
```

The above built in library resulted in

```
[attributes:protected] => Array
 (
 )
```

How should I need to access the particular attributes from an array?

Likewise, retrieving the `CurrentDivision` from the Library was made ease with calls such as `$getCurrentDivision->findWithSelect('CurrentDivision');` or with `$getDivision->CurrentDivision;`

Why couldn't the same function wouldn't work after retrieving an array?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [closure bind](https://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php) method of accessing private or protected properties of an object. Here's an example static function.

```php
class Helper {

    /**
    * Helper method to access private
    * or protected properties of an object
    * using the closure bind method
    */
    public static function accessPrivate($object, $property) {
        $bind = Closure::bind(
            function($prop) {
                return $this->$prop;
            },
            $object,
            $object
        );
        return $bind($property);
    }
}
```

Useage:

```php
$code = Helper::accessPrivate($checkAccount, "Code");
```

Comment: Is it possible to write our custom built-In functions. See towards my edit made to the posted question. Why didn't the above function calls didn't worked? Since then, I used to get empty array when I was about to call these built-In function

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about `WooCommerce` or that PHP library, `Exact Online`. I was only advising how you can access private and protected properties of objects.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the protected attributes from an array you will find in the below piece of snippets

```
$checkAccount = $Accounts->filter("Email eq 'nishanth@gmail.com'");
$getAccountId = $checkAccount[0]->ID;
$getAccountCode = $checkAccount[0]->Code;
```

---

Since I had tried with `findWithSelect()` and `find()`:

```
$Accounts->filter("Email eq 'nishanth@gmail.com'")[0]->findWithSelect('ID');
```

But didn't yield any values resulted in blank values